# User sub-sites - CMS Multisite or other solution

Tags: content-management-system, subdomain

I've been thinking about an online idea for about 3-4 years now and can't get it out of my head so I've decided to act upon it and see if I can get it working. Currently working a POC and design layout which I plan to tender for development.

The main part of the portal and most important component involves user sub-sites. I am unsure how to tackle the process for a user to create a sub-site during the registration process and/or what path to take.

Let's say the main site is www.abc.net - the user would then register a sub-site based on the credentials they input. E.g. user1.abc.net, mysite.abc.net or joeblog.abc.net...  whatever they want and so forth. No SEO required - The site templates are fairly basic and the sub-sites will be accessible through the main site. So the process to be:

1. User logs onto main site and registers
2. During registration, user enters details including sub-site name they want
3. Select the template they want - basically different colour schemes. Functionality to be the same for all templates
4. their site is created
5. when the user is logged on they get directed to their sub-site
6. Ability to edit their sub-site - add content and add extra pages, change details…. etc
7. General users (registered or anonymous) would be able to browse and search content to the sub-sites via the main site.

Each sub-site to be independent from each other - no content sharing. Basically they are separate websites hosted as sub-sites but need they need some type of editing available like a CMS. Not sure if a shared CMS is possible but the owner has to be able to modify content to their own sub-site.

So my question are…

Do I try and use a Drupal/Wordpress/Joomla CMS with multisite functionality?

Do I try a solution where I have a collection of simple sites that I use for sub-sites, each to have their own database and some type of CMS or WYSIWYG for editing? Is separate CMS even possible for each Sub-site?

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this would not be possible as the CMS would not have access to your server where the sub-domain is created.

It would be possible to offer something similer using Joomla as it offers the option to apply custom styles (templates) to different pages. You would however have to adopt the following URL convention `www.yourdomain.com/userselectedtext`.

You can then have a page where users register with your site and the cms creates their page.

User permissions in joomla can be set so only the owner of a particular page can view or edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this source: http://www.drupalgardens.com/. Google what platform is it based on.  Maybe you'll find some information. Read also about this extension: http://www.joomplace.com/administration-extensions/multisitescontrol.html. It's for Joomla sites. I used this component  for  multisites content management. Maybe it will help you too.